# Sorting column in SQL version MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am using MySQL 5.5 version to write the SQL query to do the sorting. My problem is I cannot sort the column `name` properly using below the SQL query.

```html
select t.id,t.name
from
(
select t.*, cast((case when col1_col2_ref > 0 
                      then 
                        substring_index(modified_name,'-',1)
                  else 
                     modified_name
                  end
                  ) as unsigned) col1
          , cast((case when    col1_col2_ref > 0
                           and col3_ref > 0
                       then 
                          substr(modified_name,(col1_col2_ref + 1),(col3_ref - (col1_col2_ref + 1)))
                       when col1_col2_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col1_col2_ref + 1))
                  end) as unsigned) col2
          , cast((case when    col3_ref > 0
                           and col4_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col3_ref + 1),(col4_ref - (col3_ref + 1)))
                       when col3_ref > 0
                       then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col3_ref + 1))
                  end) as unsigned) col3
          , cast((case when col4_ref > 0
                        then 
                         substr(modified_name,(col4_ref + 1))
                   end) as unsigned) col4
from
(
select t.*,substring_index(name,' ',1) modified_name
          ,locate('-',name,1) col1_col2_ref
          ,locate('/',name,1) col3_ref
          ,locate('/',name,locate('/',name,1)+1) col4_ref
  from filing_code_management t
) t
) t
order by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

This is my db link to show my sorting error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bcb32a6b47d0d5b061fd401d0888bdc3

Actually I want to sort the column `name` pattern like below the expected result table sample:

```html
id  |  name
33     100 PENTADBIRAN
40     100-1 Perundangan
46     100-1-1 Penggubalan/Penyediaan/Pindaan Undang-Undang/Peraturan
48     100-1/1/1 Undang-Undang Kecil Kerja Di Jalan 1996
49     100-1/1/2 Undang-Undang Kecil Peruntukan Mengenai Lesen Bersesama (Majlis Perbandaran Klang) 1992
264    100-6 Pengurusan Mesyuarat
265    100-6-1 Mesyuarat Dalam Jabatan
266    100-6-1-1 Mesyuarat Penuh Bulanan  SUP
267    100-6-1-2 Mesyuarat Khas Belanjawan JKEW
303    100-6-2 Mesyuarat Luar Jabatan
304    (S)100-6-2-1 Mesyuarat Dewan Undangan Negeri JKK
305    (R)100-6-2-2 Mesyuarat Majlis Kerajaan Negeri (MMKN) JKK
306    (S)100-6-2-3 Mesyuarat Tindakan Ekonomi Selangor (MTES) SUP
455    100-7 Kemudahan (Fasiliti)
456    100-7-1 Tempahan/Penggunaan Premis Ibu Pejabat dan Cawangan JKP
457    100-7-1-1 Bilik Mesyuarat/Auditorium
```

My error sorting in MySQL 5.5 result, it cannot sort properly in the table.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2KJq.png)

Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be almost impossible to handle accurately using MySQL 5.7 or earlier.  Honestly you should _normalize_ your data and get each ID value into a separate column.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me?

Comment: How did you end up with this table design?

Comment: You must create proper expression for sorting. It must: a) remove leading `(?)` if exists, b) extract prefix, c) normalize its components, d) then sort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen End up design like this sample, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=6b12a4d42359cb30f27a5bfb9d0c8210 This sample data is a little bit different in my problem db sample

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Akina , Hope yours can guide me or show me the sample to solve this. Thanks a lot

Comment: So what is wrong with the result in your new fiddle?

Comment: Thanks @Nick comment. I have updated error picture in my question. The error is my column `name ` cannot sort properly in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query which I think will sort in the order you desire. The innermost subquery splits the `name` field at the first space; removes any text enclosed in `()` at the beginning of the result and then replaces `/` with `-`. The subquery outside that then splits the resultant string into 1 to 4 pieces on `-`, and conditional aggregation is used to put those values into `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`. This subquery is then joined to the main table on the `id` field and the result is ordered by `col1` through `col4`:

```
select t.*
from filing_code_management t
join (
select id,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN f.n = 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(modified_name, '-', f.n), '-', -1) END) AS UNSIGNED) col1,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN f.n = 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(modified_name, '-', f.n), '-', -1) END) AS UNSIGNED) col2,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN f.n = 3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(modified_name, '-', f.n), '-', -1) END) AS UNSIGNED) col3,
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN f.n = 4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(modified_name, '-', f.n), '-', -1) END) AS UNSIGNED) col4
from
(
select t.id, replace(substr(substring_index(t.name,' ',1), locate(')', substring_index(t.name,' ',1))+1), '/', '-') modified_name
  from filing_code_management t
) t
join (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) f
  on length(replace(t.modified_name, '-', '')) <= length(t.modified_name) - f.n + 1
group by id
) c on t.id = c.id
order by c.col1, c.col2, c.col3, c.col4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=d7ea796a15cfbcdf3a6f378761078c5b)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm always up for a challenge, and it's (hopefully) not OP's fault they're stuck with 5.5 and the data structure that they have...

Comment: Appalling schema design is NOT the fault of the version

Comment: @Hi, Nick. Sorry disturb. Just now I show my client. They said that is possible don't replace - to /, just remain what are they giving the data? Have you any ideas that don't replace and can sort the column name?

Comment: on length(replace(t.modified_name, '-', '')) <= length(t.modified_name) - f.n + 1 Can you explain on this query? I am not quite clear on this part

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency that replace won't show up in the results (see the [fiddle]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=aa299c883ea6c667bba558c9ad18a179)) so not sure why they're worried about it? It makes solving the problem a lot easier.

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency the join condition is to make sure that the number of column values produced for each number string is only equal to the number of values in it. See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f57c4fced3fb838d9eeeab09d199681d) to see how the number string is being split

Comment: @Nick Hi. I have other similar question on SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774969/get-the-certain-column-value-follow-the-condition-in-sql-version-mysql-5-5 If you have time hope you can help me. Thanks.