# Get the certain column value follow the condition in SQL version MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have the problem to get the certain value follow the condition in SQL version MySQL 5.5.

Below picture is the condtion to get the certain value. For example I want to select all category = 1 and follow the below the picture database status to show the data in the sql table, the logic to show the data is like below the picture structure, database status "show" meaning is data will show in the table.

[image: Condition to get the value and show the data]

```html
Category_id = 1 is first layer
Category_id = 2 is second layer
Category_id = 3 is third layer
Category_id = 4 is fourth layer
```

This is my dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=785bc009a50aa4c7597510858853865b

This is my select sql query

```html
select id,name,parentid,category,category_id from filing_code_management where category =1
```

This is my expect example result, if category = 1, under the parentid for category = 1 will show the id data. Because parentid number is match id number.

[image: Output 1]

Comment: Hi @nbk, can you assit me for this quesiton?

Comment: not really mysql 5.5 is very old and deprecated, even then this is to much data and i still don't understand what the result should be

Comment: your question is not clear. Also , its not understandable what is your expected result.

Comment: How the different examples are differ from each other in terms of showing the value `show` ? and the next question is in the given db<>fiddle there are two query and which one is relevant for this question ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have updated my question and db<>fiddle

Comment: @Pi Network Crytocurrency, Thanks for your clarifications but unfortunately I am still not clear about the `example tables` you shown and where to start ?

Comment: Sorry. I think I write in my question is not clear. I just want to get category =1 and which under category's parentid (parentid = id) need to show name

Comment: Ok last try, tell me you have `parentid` `category` and `categoryid`. What the query should look for in these ?  after this my second question , is the db<>fiddle query is wrong and you need correction in that ?

Comment: There are a lot of other records that show up if you just `select id,name,parentid,category,category_id
from filing_code_management
where category = 1`, why don't you want those?

Comment: @Nick ,Sujitmohanty30 Because using this query select id,name,parentid,category,category_id from filing_code_management where category = 1 can show all. But I need if parentid number is match id number. I need to show the name. For example, if parentid = 76 , id 76 data need to show in the table. I want still find all include which id is under parentid

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 parentid is under the id. So I need show all id is included parentid number

Comment: So why not `select id,name,parentid,category,category_id from filing_code_management where category = 1 and (parentid = 76 or id = 76)`?

Comment: @Nick id 76 data no come out

Comment: select id,name,parentid,category,category_id from filing_code_management where category = 1 and (parentid = 76 or id = 76) or id=76 or id=2 or id=1

This query can show. But how to show other data.

Comment: What other data? It's really unclear what you are trying to achieve. Why don't you want all the results when `category = 1`? Why *do* you want the result for `id =76`? Your question only asks for results where `category = 1`...

Comment: Because I make a tree structure. if selected data category =1 but  parentid number is match id. id data still can show even though category not =1. Sorry about it, I try to explain clear.